# Peculiar ClassCastException in removing data from LineChart<String,String>

Tags: java, javafx

Consider the following application:

[image]

I expect, by each time clicking on BUTTON, the first data of the `LineChart` be removed. The output after the clicks must be as follows:

**After 1st click**

[image]

**After 2nd click**

[image]

**After 3rd click**

[image]

However, after the first click, I get the following `ClassCastException`:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at javafx.controls@18/javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.createDataRemoveTimeline(LineChart.java:503)
    at javafx.controls@18/javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.dataItemRemoved(LineChart.java:359)
    at javafx.controls@18/javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.dataItemsChanged(XYChart.java:505)
    at javafx.controls@18/javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series$1.onChanged(XYChart.java:1474)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:239)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:211)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.remove(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:190)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MyApplication.lambda$start$0(MyApplication.java:21)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
    at javafx.controls@18/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@18/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls@18/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The code is as follows:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        LineChart<String,String> lineChart=createLineChart();

        Button button = new Button("BUTTON");

        button.setOnAction(event -> lineChart.getData().get(0).getData().remove(0));

        VBox vBox=new VBox(button,lineChart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

    }

    LineChart<String,String> createLineChart(){
        LineChart<String, String> lineChart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new CategoryAxis());
        lineChart.getData().add(new XYChart.Series<>());
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            lineChart.getData().get(0).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("X string %d".formatted(i+1), "Y string %d".formatted(i+1)));
        }
        lineChart.getXAxis().setTickLabelFont(new Font(20));
        lineChart.getYAxis().setTickLabelFont(new Font(20));
        return lineChart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Question**

Why does `ClassCastException` raise in conversion of `String` to `Number` when I have no `Number` type data?

Comment: That's a bug. The internal code for `LineChart` [assumes the type of the y-value is `Number`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.java#L505C72-L505C72) (or a subclass thereof). You can probably work around it by turning off animation (`lineChart.setAnimated(false);`).

Comment: Thank you. I turned off the animation and it worked. But, how does this bug depend on animation property? Shouldn't it happen, nonetheless, when both X and Y axes are string typed?

Comment: The method in question (`LineChart.createDataRemoveTimeline()`) is called internally as part of animating the chart when a data point is removed. The method caches the removed value (assuming, incorrectly, the y-value is numeric), I think in case the data is added back before the animation completes. Turning off animation prevents the method from being invoked.

Comment: @SedJ601 Agreed. There is also a close vote for "cannot reproduce", which makes no sense to me. I copied and pasted the code exactly as-is, and the stack trace appeared as reported when I pressed the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the implementation of `LineChart`. I cannot find an active bug report for it at https://bugs.openjdk.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa.

The issue arises in the call to the method `createDataRemoveTimeline(...)` (found [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.java#L502) in the current implementation) which is implemented as:

```
    private Timeline createDataRemoveTimeline(final Data<X,Y> item, final Node symbol, final Series<X,Y> series) {
        Timeline t = new Timeline();
        // save data values in case the same data item gets added immediately.
        XYValueMap.put(item, ((Number)item.getYValue()).doubleValue());

        t.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(item.currentYProperty(),
                item.getCurrentY()), new KeyValue(item.currentXProperty(),
                item.getCurrentX())),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), actionEvent -> {
                    if (symbol != null) getPlotChildren().remove(symbol);
                    removeDataItemFromDisplay(series, item);
                    XYValueMap.clear();
                },
                new KeyValue(item.currentYProperty(),
                item.getYValue(), Interpolator.EASE_BOTH),
                new KeyValue(item.currentXProperty(),
                item.getXValue(), Interpolator.EASE_BOTH))
        );
        return t;
    }
```

The implementation caches values that are removed (as I understand it this is needed in case the same values are added back while the animation for their removal is progressing) in a `Map<Data<X,Y>, Double>`. This assumes the y-value is a `Number` (note the cast in the second line of the method) which of course is not necessarily true. I think this should be implemented with a `Map<Data<X,Y>, Y>`, though I have not fully analyzed the code.

The `createDataRemoveTimeline(...)` method is called from the `dataItemRemoved(...)` method (invoked when an item is removed from one of the data series) but only if `animated` is set to true. Hence one work around is to turn off animation:

```
lineChart.setAnimated(false);
```